# deserialize mongodb document on browser javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

New to mongodb and this is more a convention question.  I have a python server on the backend that retrieves documents from mongodb and serves as REST API.  The API returns data after serializing it using the bson.json_util library.

return bson.json_util.dumps(response, default=default)

This serialized json has an extra layer for certain data types, such as $oid for unique ids, $date for dates and so on. 
My question is whether there is a javascript deserializer that takes the json and converts it into an object ? Otherwise the data needs to be accessed with an extra layer (start_time.$date).  Or is the convention to strip this layer in the API implementation ?

Sample data after being serialized.

```
{
    "name": "test_name_0",
    "start_time": {
      "$date": 1493650775227
    },
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "59074d577653512111045b3f"
    },
    "suite_id": {
      "$oid": "59074d577653512111045b3e"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a snippet of how your data looks when it comes out of the serializer

Comment: added an example data after being serialized.  Thanks

Comment: Could you also post what you would like the data to ultimately look like. If that is your question, what should the data look like, please clarify that and I will answer accordingly.

Comment: I guess the question is if there is a javascript deserializer for this type of json.  That is, in order to access start_time, we would need to access it with the data path, json["start_time"]["$date"].  Instead, is there a way to deserialize it so a $date value turns into a Date() object that can be accessed via deserialized_json.start_time.  I'm assume elements like $date, $oid are there to specify the data type, so it would make sense if a deserializer already existed to make use of that info.